# Select from Attribute Table with step by 2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, select

I want to select from the Attribute table all items with step by 2 (select one item, I don't select the next one, etc). How can I do that? I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

This expression shows how to select every other record.  You have to run it on a short or long integer field that is incremented consecutively.  If you add or delete a record you'll have to re-increment the ID field before running mod query again.

```
MOD(OBJECTID, 2) = 0
```

Selects the second record and ever other after that

```
MOD(OBJECTID, 2) = 1
```

Select the first record and ever other after that

Comment: That would only work with consecutive objectid's wouldn't it? A user could have deleted oid's 2, 4, 6, etc.

Comment: It didn't work... any other thoughts?

Comment: Create another ID field (short or long integer) and increment from 1....x and try it on that.  If you delete or add a feature you'll have to re-increment the ID field before running the mod query.

Comment: @NikosGr, what about it didn't work? What results/error message did you get?